# Python import all functions from folder

Tags: python

I have a folder containing various Python files, each including some functions called tasks. I want to do two things:

Instead of writing

```
from module.file1 import function1, function2
from module.file2 import function3
```

I would prefer to do:

```
from module import function1, function2, function3
```

In addition to that, I need a list of all functions names (as `str`) which available in this directory (excluding built-ins).

So far I tried writing a `__init__.py` with the following content:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))

functions = []

for m in modules:
    if isfile(m) and not m.endswith('__init__.py'):
        functions = [getattr(m, f) for f in dir(m) if callable(getattr(m, f))]

print(functions)
```

However, `functions` now contains all built-in functions but not the one was was looking for. In addition, how do I "return" the functions for import and how can I get the list of function names (string only) for further use?

Comment: `m` is a string, not a module.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Changing it to `getattr(m, f)` somehow helps, now `functions` contains a lot of stuff. It does include all builtin functions though and not the function I was hoping for.

Comment: What you get are actually the methods of `str`.

Comment: Why? `dir(m)` should list the attributes of the modules identified by the path, right?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way how to solve it.

`__init__.py` looks as follows

```
__all__ = []

import pkgutil
import inspect

for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)

    for fname, value in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction):
        if fname.startswith('__'):
            continue

        if value.__module__ != module.__name__:
            continue

        globals()[fname] = value
        __all__.append(fname)
```

It does the additional check for the module name to make sure I don't list imported functions but only those defined in the module. In the other file I then include it with:

```
from tasks import __all__ as function_names
import tasks

functions = [getattr(tasks, f) for f in function_names]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been looking for a way to do this, but keep running into answers for importing `modules` and not `functions`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you use to filter is incorrect, try the following -

```
functions = [getattr(m, f) for f in dir(m) if callable(getattr(m, f))]
```

p.s consider using [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module

Comment: As already noted under the question, `m` is a string, so what do you expect `dir(m)` to return?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changing it to `getattr(m, f)` somehow helps, now `functions` contains a lot of stuff. It does include all builtin functions though and not the function I was hoping for. It also does not explain the main part of the question how to "return" the functions so that the imports work and how to get a string list of functions.

Comment: See @ThierryLathuille comment, you should probably make sure you use the modules and not the strings.